# Time waiting for submission to student section of law journals

Tags: journals, online-publication, law

I have submitted a small piece in two legal Journals, one for the Journal's blog and one for an on-line version of it but haven't heard from them for quite a while. These sections are the only ones where they publish student submissions. I submitted to the first one on 12 May, didn't get any response and I e-mailed them on 27 May just to make sure they received it and I finally got a response on May 31 asking for extended cuts. I expanded the article to meet the second journal's standards and I submitted it on 25 June. Meanwhile I submitted the cut version to the first journal on 3 August. On August 18 I tried to send an e-mail to confirm that the second journal had received my piece and the e-mail that I sent to the original submission address failed to deliver (I received a relative notification). Anyway, I e-mailed the general submissions address of the second journal to let them know of the problem and ask if I need to re-submit and have received no response until today.

I know that it may seem that it is not a long time but the short version of the paper is 4 pages and the long one 7, so it shouldn't take much time for the editors to finish reviewing it (another journal responded within two weeks). Also I need to increase the number of my publications to apply for some positions asap. Should I try to re-contact any journal or should I just keep waiting?

Comment: No they're not, they actually are journals of Harvard and Columbia and the one that rejected me was of Stanford. They just have these sections for smaller parts, and they only accept submissions from students in those. Plus in my field it is very common to submit to more than one journals, at least as far as the US are concerned.

Comment: If you are submitting to a special kind of journal (smaller parts, student only, whatever) or in a field with unusual publication practices (where multiple submissions and 1-week decisions are normal, as you say), then you will certainly need to [edit] the details of your situation into your question before anyone can answer it. How can anybody answer your question without knowing the context?

Comment: It was two weeks after all, I did not remember correctly. I made the changes, hope they help.